# Using Cloud Firestore with App engine (PHP)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

According to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/firestore-or-datastore) I can use Google Firestore with App engine PHP 7.2. But I cannot find how to integrate the Firestore client inside the App Engine environment.